# GitLab CI/CD pytests

Tags: gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci, python-poetry

I'm trying to understand one particular job in CI/CD pipeline, which has the following logic:

```
  test:
    stage: test
    image: python:3.8
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
        when: never
      - when: always
    before_script:
      - mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh
      - ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      - echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | ssh-add -
      - pip3 install poetry==$POETRY_VERSION
      - poetry install
      - source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate
    script:
      - pytest tests
```

For now it seems like we're going to run multiple unit tests under the tests folder in the root of our GitLab project using the python image to actually run the python code, which is more or less obvious why. To actually run the tests we would need some dependencies that are listed in the poetry.lock file, so we install poetry package manager and all the needed libraries. My understanding ends here. I'm particularly interested in the first 4 commands and the last one (activate something like a virtual env?) under the before_script tag. Why do we need them and what do they do? The same goes for the rules tag. Why do we check for this $CI_COMMIT_TAG variable? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI_COMMIT_TAG is one of [GitLab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/), populated by gitlab itself on every CI/CD job

```
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
        when: never
      - when: always
```

Basically says 'skip this job if commit has an attached tag, run otherwise'. So your tests should run on any untagged commits.

The first 4 commands are needed to configure SSH agent in a container, let's break in down:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

create .ssh directory and restrict access to it. This is necessary, because by default, there is no .ssh folder, and ~/.ssh/known_hosts is file used by ssh to validate remote server keys

```
ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

this command gets fingerprint of gitlab.com public key and puts it into ~/.ssh/known_hosts. Without filling known hosts, any ssh command, aimed towards gitlab.com would ask you to confirm if you trust this server or not. This exact command kinda pointless from security perspective, because it just blindly trusts whatever server host key is present, and doesn't protect from MitM attacks. The proper way of doing it should be manually adding this key to your pipelines, i.e. by storing it inside some variable and echoing into ~/.ssh/known_hosts . See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-host-keys-fingerprints to get correct known_hosts entries

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

this command launches ssh-agent - so every subsequent SSH command won't prompt you for password.

```
echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | ssh-add -
```

adds a deploy key to ssh-agent, so any subsequent SSH commands would automatically use it.

Personally, depending on your risk model, I'd skip all "ssh-agent" stuff and just echo your deploy into ~/.ssh/id_rsa. There reason why agent is used might be to not ever store your deploy key on any filesystem, since variables are stored in memory, and ssh-agents also work from memory.

Finally, `source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate` just enters a virtualenv of this project. Poetry is a neat packaging and dependency management tool,when you ran a `poetry install` command, it automatically generated a venv for you. `poetry env info --path` prints path to venv root directory, and `source` command executes instructions in `bin/activate` inside venv.

This is also seems unnecessary, because you can just run

```
poetry run pytest tests
```

inside `script:` section, and it will execute pytest inside poetry env.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Awesome explanation.